# How to create a pop-up upon selection of points in a plot in a Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, modal-dialog

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux

mtcars2 <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt", "am", "gear")]


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300,
                      # Equivalent to: click = clickOpts(id = "plot_click")
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           actionButton("show", "Show points"),
           verbatimTextOutput("brush_info")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars2, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  })

  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Important message",
      "This is an important message!",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })

  output$click_info <- renderPrint({
    # Because it's a ggplot2, we don't need to supply xvar or yvar; if this
    # were a base graphics plot, we'd need those.
    nearPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_click, addDist = TRUE)
  })

  output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_brush)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Right now this table shows me the points I have selected on the graph. This works, however I would like to automatically create a popup with that data as soon you have selected something. So the functionality I have right now with the button "Show points" but then with the input of the `brushedPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_brush)`

Any thoughts on how I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `reactiveVal` that contains the 'brushed points'. This requires an observer that updates this `reactiveVal` whenever the brushed points change. We can then create another `observeEvent` that listens to changes in our `reactiveVal` and make it trigger a `modalDialog` whenever new points are selected. Hope this helps!

By the way, you could also just let the `observeEvent` listen to `input$plot1_brush`, but then you would have to run `brushedPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_brush)` twice, once for the `renderText` and once for the `modalDialog`, so I would suggest the approach with `reactiveVal`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)   # For nicer ggplot2 output when deployed on Linux

mtcars2 <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt", "am", "gear")]

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300,
                      # Equivalent to: click = clickOpts(id = "plot_click")
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           verbatimTextOutput("brush_info")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars2, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  })

  selected_points <- reactiveVal()

  # update the reactiveVal whenever input$plot1_brush changes, i.e. new points are selected.
  observeEvent(input$plot1_brush,{
    selected_points( brushedPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_brush))
  })

  # show a modal dialog
  observeEvent(selected_points(), ignoreInit=T,ignoreNULL = T, {
    if(nrow(selected_points())>0){
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Important message",
      paste0("You have selected: ",paste0(rownames(selected_points()),collapse=', ')),
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
    }
  })

  output$brush_info <- renderPrint({
    selected_points()
  })

  output$click_info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(mtcars2, input$plot1_click, addDist = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```